# How to test a label with QUnit in a custom validator?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, validation, qunit

You can use a regular RequiredValidator for i.e. a textbox but not for a label, so I've added a custom validator and use JQuery function to validate it. All works fine but I would like to be able to unit test it.

What changes would I need to do to, to test this function:

```
function LabelRequired_Validate(sender, args) {
    if (sender == $("#ctl00_cphMain_Agent2_Agent_Agent_LabelValidator1")[0]) {
        if ($("#ctl00_cphMain_Agent2_Agent_Agent_ValueLabel")[0].innerText.length > 0) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    } else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

with this QUnit test (or similar):

```
test("Servicing_Topup_Branch_label_is_valid", function() {
    var span = $("span[id$=ValueLabel]");
    $(span).text(10 + " characters long");

    var args = { IsValid: true, Value: "" };
    LabelRequired_Validate($(span), args)

    ok(args.IsValid == true, "Validation Passed!");
});
```

Here is my custom validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="LabelValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$Resources:Main,RequiredFieldWarning %>"
        Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="LabelRequired_Validate" EnableViewState="False"
        class="alertMsg">
    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few changes to both the target and test functions. Here's how it works.

To the target:

```
function LabelRequired_Validate(sender, args) {
    if (sender == $("span[id$=LabelValidator1]")[0]) {
        if ($("span[id$=ValueLabel]")[0].innerText.length > 0) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    } else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

And to the test:

```
test("Servicing_Topup_Branch_label_required_is_valid", function() {
    expect(2);

    var span1 = $("span[id$=LabelValidator1]");
    var span2 = $("span[id$=ValueLabel]");

    $(span2).text(18 + " characters long");
    var args = { IsValid: true, Value: "" };
    LabelRequired_Validate(span1[0], args)

    ok(args.IsValid == true, "Not empty label returns Valid - Passed!");


    $(span2).text("");
    args = { IsValid: true, Value: "" };
    LabelRequired_Validate(span1[0], args)

    ok(args.IsValid == false, "Empty label returns NotValid - Passed!");

});
```